# WOL doesn't wake PC (keyboard does). How to fix?

Tags: power-management, realtek, wakeonlan

I manage to get my PC to hibernate through **pm-hibernate --quirk-s3-bios**. Suspend strangely enough doesn't work (PC reboots immediately to a new state and Ubuntu starts a disk check, but that's only as side information).

When hibernated, as soon as I touch the keyboard, the PC resumes correctly from hibernation. However, sending a WOL packet doesn't wake the PC. How can I detect and fix what is wrong?

Mobo: ASROCK B75 Pro3-M, RTL8111e driver installed from Realtek site, Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

Many thanks !

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the kernel. Please check http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a malfunctioning motherboard.